# Push notifications are not being sent from Firebase to Android

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I have added firebase dependencies and included `google-services.json`. I am able to use Firebase database successfully. But Push notifications are not being sent from fireabse console.

Please let me know what is wrong here.

I have following classes

```
   public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

And Messaging Service

```
public class GalleryMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        send();

    }

    private void send() {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("First Notification");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 001;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

I have added following in Manifest.xml as well

```
<service android:name="com.doublenine.apps.ui.GalleryMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="com.doublenine.apps.ui.FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
         notification message.  for more. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
```

`FirebaseIDService` class looks incomplete as I don't know what to write in `sendRegistrationToServer()`

Comment: are you testing it on Android 8.0+?

Comment: No. I am testing in android 5 and 6

Comment: try printing something in `onMessageReceived` function to check if its firebase issue or notification issue